# minikube fails to start kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, rhel7, kubernetes

I am new to `Kubernetes` and was trying to build a cluster using `minikube`. While trying to start the cluster using `minikube`   , it fails with the following error

```
$  minikube start --vm-driver=kvm
Starting local Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
 140.01 MB / 140.01 MB [============================================] 100.00% 0s
E1107 12:30:30.581841   13820 start.go:150] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error with pre-create check: "Unable to connect to kvm driver, did you add yourself to the libvirtd group?".
```

==========================================================================

I have already added the user to libvirt group.

```
$ id
uid=1010(zaman) gid=1011(zaman) groups=1011(zaman),498(libvirt)
```

OS information is as follows:

```
 $ cat /etc/redhat-release
 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
 $ minikube version
 minikube version: v0.23.0
```

Please suggest how to resolve the issue.

Comment: just a shot in the dark.. after adding the user to the group did you relogin? or open a new terminal?

Comment: Thanks for your comment . I got the hint there . libvirtd service was not running